# Bash command/script to diff all mytestN.out and testN.out

Tags: linux, bash, shell, shell-script

I have an executable that I will test with all input files and make a corresponding number of output files (I can do this part). Then I will diff the newly made files, called mytestN.out, with the files with the correct outputs, called testN.out and pipe it into a file called difftestN.txt. Then I will check each of the difftest.txt and if it is empty, print "success" and if not empty, print "difference found".

For example, I will do

```
./Executable < test1.in > mytest1.out
```

for the N number of test.in's.
I found that this can be done with this

```
for f in test*.in; do ./tetris <"$f" >"my${f%in}svg"; done
```

Then I will do diff command for all mytest.out's against all test.out's.

```
diff mytest1.out test1.out > difftest1.txt
```

I'm not sure how to do this for all testN's.
I think this is the right approach:

```
for f in mytest*.svg; do diff "$f" "###what goes here?###" > "diff${f%in}txt"; done
```

but I don't know what goes in after "$f", and the diff will be piped into a diffmytestN.txt, but i want difftestN.txt

Then, I want to check each of the difftest.txt's and if it is empty, print "success" and if it is not empty, print "difference found"

Comment: `for f in test*.out; do diff "my$f" "$f" ...`?

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust this for an arbitrarily large number of files named as you mentioned. Here are 4 test files' contents I used:
test1: one
mytest1: 1
test2: two
mytest2: two

```
for i in {1..2}; do 
    diff test${i}.out mytest${i}.out &>/dev/null
    es=$?
    if [ $es -ne 0 ]; then 
        echo "difference found"
    else 
        echo "success"
    fi
done
```

Output:

```
difference found
success
```

I realize I have not answered your literal question, because you asked for files holding the output of diff. If you really must have that, you could instead change the code:

```
  diff test${i}.out mytest${i}.out > difftest${i}.txt

  if ! [[ -s difftest${i} ]]; then 
      echo success
  else
      echo "difference found"
  fi
```

It's probably useful to keep in mind that, should your program ever try to compare a file with content to a non-existent file, it'll create output to stderr that looks as if there was a substantive difference between the file and non-existent file. This should be fine since only stdout goes into *.txt.

Comment: Correction, this should have read, 'should your program even try to compare and empty file to a non-existent file, it'll wind up printing difference found.'